# How can we push UISplitVIewController to a UINavigationController

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Is it possible to push SplitViewController on Navigation Controller?

I am getting this error :

`Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller <UINavigationController: 0x9618830>.`

Thank you.

Comment: Ya I know this is very clear but i want to know if there is any way to implement this. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

This is because Apple doesn't want you to push split view controllers into navigation controllers. Their guidelines say that if you use a UISplitViewController, it has to be visible at all times in your app, except from overlaying it with modal view controllers.

Comment: Hi, Thanx for your great reply. Can you edit your post by providing an example on how to `overlay the UISplitViewController with a modal view`? Thanx.

Comment: Using a modal view is the same regardless of whether you have a UISplitViewController or something else below. To show a view controller modally, use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` on `UIViewController`.

Answer (score -1):

I did manage to put a splitview controller as an item in a tab bar controller

Comment: If you are providing an answer for this question, please do not state it as a question. Also, please be sure that your answer provides an answer to the original poster's question.