# First iPad Application : Facing Problems

Tags: ios, ipad

I am trying to get a split controller's view by calling it in AppDelegate, but it's not showing up. Here is the code written in `didfinishlaunchwithoptions` :

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

SplitViewController *splitViewController = [[SplitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplitViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:splitViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

And i have SplitViewController.xib with view red colored. But iPad simulator turn up with a black screen.

Please see what can be the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors or output in the console?  Perhaps the xib file's "view" property is not set or something like that.

Comment: no I am taking care of that, but a different one:

Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller <UINavigationController: 0x687f460>.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855454/how-can-we-push-uisplitviewcontroller-to-a-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: but i tried by removing the NC object and setting the window's rootViewController = splitViewController; But this also seems not working. I also tried by adding the view of splitViewController on window, but this again results in a black window on simulator.

Comment: And once again, I will ask if there were any console messages...

Comment: I have added the GDB message below..please see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller

This is the key here. Try adding your split view controller directly to your window.

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
```

Comment: My SplitViewController class is a subclass of UISplitViewController, i guess I am not doing any mistakes here?

Comment: 2012-03-18 09:30:56.475 MapApp[707:f803] Splitview controller <SplitViewController: 0x686c490> is expected to have a master view controller before its used!
2012-03-18 09:30:56.477 MapApp[707:f803] Splitview controller <SplitViewController: 0x686c490> is expected to have a detail children before its used!
2012-03-18 09:30:56.478 MapApp[707:f803] Split view controller <SplitViewController: 0x686c490> should have its children set before layout!

Comment: if your splitview is made correctly it should work. but you can try "[self.window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];".

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting up the view correctly in your nib.  Split view controllers need to have two views set, a master view and a detail view.  Your detail view is not set so the viewcontroller is never created.

[The docs on UISplitViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) state that you need to have the `viewControllers` property set to exactly two views.  I imagine you are only setting one (the red view).

**edit:** You didn't set the master view either....so it is close to what I said before in the comments (the view is not set properly)

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDemoMasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[AppDemoMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppDemoMasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];

UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];    

AppDemoDetailViewController *masterViewController = [[[AppDemoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppDemoDetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];

UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];

self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];

self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
```