# How to dismiss UISplitViewController when a button pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

In my iPad app. I'm working on `UISplitViewController`. In the `DetailViewController` of `UISplitViewController` there is button. When that button is pressed it's navigate to another view controller. In the another view controller I no need to `UISplitViewController`. How to dismiss `UISplitViewController`. I have tried a lot and googled,but I did not find any solution. It's killing my time so if any one have worked on it please guide me and post sample code.

I'm using this code

```
-(void)imgButtonpressed:(id)sender
{
    MenuItemsListViewController *menuview=[[MenuItemsListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuItemsListViewController" bundle:nil];

    menuview.modelArray = imagesArray;
    menuview.image = [sender tag]*2;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:menuview animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apple doesn't want you to push split view controllers into navigation controllers. Their guidelines say that if you use a UISplitViewController, it has to be visible at all times in your app(Hence you cannot delete it), except from overlaying it with modal view controllers.

How about presenting your viewcontroller modally?

```
MenuItemsListViewController *menuview=[[MenuItemsListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuItemsListViewController" bundle:nil];

menuview.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self.splitViewController presentViewController:menuview animated:YES completion:nil];
```

source: [How can we push UISplitVIewController to a UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855454/how-can-we-push-uisplitviewcontroller-to-a-uinavigationcontroller)

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem when working with UISplitView. In fact, i still got a problem now when i finally figured out how to push a splitview on top of a rootviewcontroller.

So, I believe there are lots of newbs out there who are frustrated by this problem. I tried to figure out the solution by lots of reading here.

Here's what i do (you can do the same with any other view) :

This will dismiss a splitview and push another splitview:

```
SplitViewController *split = [[SplitViewController alloc]init];
    self.leftController = [[LeftViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *leftNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:leftController];
    self.rightController = [[RightViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *rightNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rightController];
    split.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftNav,rightNav, nil];
    split.delegate = self.rightController;

    YourAppDelegate *delegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.window.rootViewController = split;
```

And the second option is :

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];

    [allViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:split];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
```

Hopefully this would be a help to others who are stumbled with the same problem.

Cheers!